# how to ignore entire dlls or namespaces with xunit.net?

Tags: c#, .net-core, tdd, xunit.net

**Question:**
How can I configure xunit to ignore dlls, namespaces or classes from code coverage? Something like what is done with regex expressions in a [runsettings file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/customizing-code-coverage-analysis?view=vs-2019) for mstest?

**Why I need it:**
Imagine that I have received some swagger and auto-generated some code. I could but in most cases won't unit test it. Mainly because I only need a portion of what was generated.

I end up with an bad code coverage and would like to remove external portions of code from coverage analysis.

Thanks!

Comment: xunit doesn't do code coverage directly. suggest reading more about your code coverage tool and/or rewriting the question without that presumption

Comment: Why not remove auto-generated code you don't need?

Comment: @Fabio Everytime I update the service swagger I will need to repeat that cleanup. I wanted to avoid that.